# Azure App Service Application Insight show API wait for long time

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I am using Azure Application Insight on App Service

[image]

As shown in the picture taken from Application Insight, sometimes the API will wait for long time before executing the real operation which is after 22 minutes

Any idea why it will "wait and do nothing"? Its just on and off getting this senario

Thanks

Comment: is it an async operation?

Comment: yes its an async operation

Comment: it seems to me it's a long running operation with no cancelation/timeout. But it's just a guess and there's no code

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be caused by various factors, including

1. Please verify the Application Insights SDK version; if it is old, please upgrade it to the latest version.
2. It appears that **ServerTelemetryChannel** uses sync-over-async calls when **disposing** due to async calls in long-running operations. **GetAwaiter().The calling thread is also blocked by GetResult()**Find reference in the [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/telemetry-channels#built-in-telemetry-channels).